# C++ Struct creation error does not name a type

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I run my program, following error occurs each time when I use `temp->`.

[Error] request for member 'key' in '* temp', which is of pointer type 'NodeType {aka Node*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

What is wrong with the code.

```
struct Node;
typedef Node *NodeType;

int NumNodes = 0;
const int SIZE = 100;
NodeType data[SIZE];


struct Node{
int key;
NodeType *left, *right;
};

NodeType *newNode(int value){
  if(NumNodes == SIZE)
    cout << "This Node Pool is full." << endl;
    exit(1);

  NodeType *temp = &data[NumNodes++];
  temp->key  = value;                  
  temp->left = temp->right = NULL;     
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: which part of the error you dont understand? You managed to confuse yourself with the typedef. Remove it and the mistake should be crystal clear

Comment: In practice avoid `typedef`-ing pointers (like you did for `NodeType`). It makes your code unreadable. Explicitly code `Node*` when needed.  BTW, your error happens when you *compile* your program. Do enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g ` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Learn to compile on the command line. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: when i remove `typedef` it gives an error NodeType does not name a type

Comment: ... I didnt mean "just remove the line" but replace `NodeType` with `Node*` and then remove the typedef ....

Comment: It is now giving the same error for `Node`

Comment: Is your intent to store the nodes in the array and building the tree from pointers to those nodes, or is it to allocate the nodes dynamically and individually?

Comment: I am intended to create binary search tree by using dynamic data and I must attempt to store the numbers in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Node
{
int key;
Node *left, *right;
};

int NumNodes = 0;
const int SIZE = 100;
Node data[SIZE];

Node* nNode(int value)
{

if(NumNodes == SIZE)
{
    cout << "This is full" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
else
{        
    Node* temp = &data[NumNodes++];
    temp->key  = value;                  
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL; 
    return temp;
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `exit(1)` statement for this program. I don't think you need this here.

Answer (score 1):

If we get rid of the confusing typedef, this is what you have:

```
struct Node;

int NumNodes = 0;
const int SIZE = 100;
Node* data[SIZE];

struct Node{
    int key;
    Node **left, **right;
};

Node** newNode(int value){
  if(NumNodes == SIZE)
    cout << "This Node Pool is full." << endl;
    exit(1);

  Node** temp = &data[NumNodes++];
  temp->key  = value;                  
  temp->left = temp->right = NULL;     
  return temp;
}
```

As you can see, you have added a (needless) level of indirection, storing pointers to pointers in the tree, and having a pool of `Node` pointers instead of a pool of `Node`s.

Remove the typedef and use `Node` insted of `NodeType`:

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    Node *left, *right;
};

int NumNodes = 0;
const int SIZE = 100;
Node data[SIZE];


Node* newNode(int value){
  if(NumNodes == SIZE) {
    cout << "This Node Pool is full." << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  Node* temp = &data[NumNodes++];
  temp->key  = value;                  
  temp->left = temp->right = NULL;     
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got yourself confused with pointers. First get rid of `NodeType` and use `Node*` instead. It's important to know where the pointers in your program are, hiding them behind a typedef doesn't do you any favours.

Now the real error. You're trying to create a pool of objects for allocation. so the pool should be objects not pointers.

```
int NumNodes = 0;
const int SIZE = 100;
Node data[SIZE];
```

Now you allocation function should return a pointer to an object in the pool. In your code it returns `NodeType*` which is a **pointer to a pointer** (because `NodeType` is a pointer). Also very importantly you have missing braces around your if statement in `newNode` (the call to `exit` is not inside the if statement in your code). So instead

```
Node *newNode(int value) {
    if (NumNodes == SIZE) {
        cout << "This Node Pool is full." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    Node *temp = &data[NumNodes++];
    temp->key  = value;                  
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;     
    return temp;
}
```

Finally your `struct` also has pointers to pointers when it should just have normal pointers

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    Node *left, *right;
};
```

Basically you created a lot of confusion in your own mind by declaring `NodeType` as a pointer and then adding another pointer on top.